# Automated excel worksheet export without formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, powershell, automation, document-automation

I have several hundred excel files with varying numbers of sheets within each.
I need to export each sheet as a CSV (preferably with "each","cell","in","quotes" but not necessary), ideally without any of the columns being reformatted as dates.

Is there a way to automate this? I looked into doing something with PowerShell, but everything I saw regarding Excel involves COM objects which I'm trying to avoid because I'm not familiar with them and unfortunately don't have time right now for a learning opportunity.

Comment: Have you tried VBA?

Comment: I've never worked with that before. How steep would you estimate the learning curve?

Comment: If you have python experience (or are willing to take a stab at python), https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-excel-to-csv-in-python/ might be helpful

Comment: superluminal, VBA has been around for decades. Well before Powershell was even a thought. IT's what MSOffice using for programming. You can open, Excel, start the macro recorder and use the GUI to do your steps, then, stop the recorder, and open and review the code. From there, it's just a matter of conversion for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the modules from the MS powershellgallery.com...

```
Find-Module -Name '*Excel*'

# Results
<#
Version     Name                                 Repository Description                                                                                       
-------     ----                                 ---------- -----------                                                                                       
7.1.1       ImportExcel                          PSGallery  PowerShell module to import/export Excel spreadsheets, without Excel....                          
0.1.12      PSWriteExcel                         PSGallery  Little project to create Excel files without Microsoft Excel being installed.                     
1.0.2       PSExcel                              PSGallery  Work with Excel without installing Excel                                                          
20.0.7654.0 ExcelCmdlets                         PSGallery  CData Cmdlets for Excel                                                                           
20.0.7654.0 ExcelServicesCmdlets                 PSGallery  CData Cmdlets for Excel Services                                                                  
0.1.6       BitTitan.Runbooks.Excel              PSGallery  PowerShell module for Excel-related functions and resources used in BitTitan Runbooks             
20.0.7654.0 ExcelOnlineCmdlets                   PSGallery  CData Cmdlets for Excel Online                                                                    
0.1.6       BitTitan.Runbooks.Excel.Beta         PSGallery  PowerShell module for Excel-related functions and resources used in BitTitan Runbooks             
0.6.9       ExcelPSLib                           PSGallery  Allow simple creation and manipulation of XLSX file                                               
0.0.4       Excelimo                             PSGallery  Simple project generating Excel Workbooks/Worksheets                                              
2.1         Read-ExcelFile                       PSGallery  PowerShell module to import Excel spreadsheets, without Excel....                                 
0.0.4       ProductivityTools.PSImportExcelToSQL PSGallery  Module takes all excel files in given directory and push the content to database. 
#>
```

... to read the files.

As for this...

> '...CSV (preferably with "each","cell","in","quotes"...'

... use the Export-Csv cmdlet does this by design

```
# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -Name Export-Csv).Parameters
(Get-Command -Name Export-Csv).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Export-Csv -Examples
Get-help -Name Export-Csv -Full
Get-help -Name Export-Csv -Online
```

A web search would show you examples:

> ['PowerShell convert excel to csv'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell%20convert%20excel%20to%20csv%27&t=h_&ia=web)

Example hits:

> [Convert Excel file to CSV from a PowerShell script](https://medium.com/@guimatheus92/convert-excel-file-to-csv-from-a-powershell-script-3b998b9e8c2f)
>
> [Using the ImportExcel Module: A First Look](https://www.it-splat.com/2018/10/using-importexcel-module-first-look.html)

```
Import-Excel -Path .\ddm.xlsx -WorksheetName 'DDM Data' | 
Tee-Object -Variable xlData
```